# Есть таймер с минутами и секундами, как добавить часы?

Tags: javascript, jquery

На просторах интернета нашел код таймера, в котором есть минуты и секунды, мне надо добавить часы, как это сделать? Очень срочно, помогите, пожалуйста, буду очень благодарен.

```js
function startTimer(duration, display) {
    var timer = duration, minutes, seconds;
    setInterval(function () {
        minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10);
        seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);

        minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
        seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

        display.text(minutes + ":" + seconds);

        if (--timer < 0) {
            timer = duration;
        }
    }, 1000);
}

jQuery(function ($) {
    var fiveMinutes = 60 * 5,
        display = $('#time');
    startTimer(fiveMinutes, display);
});
```

```html
<body>
    <div>Registration closes in <span id="time">05:00</span>      minutes!</div>
</body>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 5):

```js
startTimer(10 * 60 * 60 + 7 * 60 + 33, '.time');

function startTimer(goal, timer) {
  let i = a => (a - a % 1 + "").padStart(2, "0"),
    m = 60,
    h = m * m;
  timer = document.querySelector(timer);
  goal += new Date / 1000;
  setInterval(() => {
    let t = goal - new Date / 1000;
    timer.textContent = [t / h, t % h / m, t % h % m].map(i).join(":");
  }, 999);
}
```

```html
<div class="time"></div>
```

Comment: Только с ведущими нулями вывод покрасивее будет. Меняем функцию: `let i = a => \`0${parseInt(a)}\`.slice(-2);`  и вывод `timer.textContent = [i(t/h), i((t%h)/m), i((t%h)%m)].join(':');`

Comment: @Deonis согласен с Вами, сейчас подправлю, только не слайсом, а то вдруг часов больше 99

Comment: Да, в таком случае лучше `.padStart(2,'0');`

Comment: Спасибо большое, но как тут поменять селектор на класс .time?

Comment: Спасибо еще раз, очень помог)

Comment: @RomanKyktenko если помог, будьде добры тыкнуть галку и отметить ответ как принятый

Comment: @RostyslavKuzmovych спасибо за заботу, сейчас отомщу

Answer (score 1):

```
function startTimer(duration, display) {
    var timer = duration,hours, minutes, seconds;
    setInterval(function () {
        hours = parseInt(timer / 3600, 10);
        minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10);
        seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);

        hours = hours < 10 ? "0" + hours : hours;
        minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
        seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

        display.text(hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds);

        if (--timer < 0) {
            timer = duration;
        }
    }, 1000);
}

jQuery(function ($) {
    var fiveMinutes = 60 * 5,
        display = $('#time');
    startTimer(fiveMinutes, display);
});
```