# Таймер на обновлении страницы через атрибут

Tags: javascript

как можно сделать таймер на обновлении страницы? Чтобы стартовое значение задавалось через атрибут. Должно быть написано на чистом JS.

Еще вылазит ошибка: **Uncaught TypeError: timerSet.hasAttribute is not a function**

```js
window.onload = function() {
  let timerSet = document.getElementsByClassName('timer');
  let timer;
  let refresh = document.getElementsByClassName('btn-refresh');

  if (!timerSet.hasAttribute('data-timer')) {
    timerSet.setAttribute('data-widget-timer', '2 : 00');
  } else {
    timer = timerSet.getAttribute('data-timer');
  }

  refresh.onclick = function() {
    window.location.reload();
  }
};
```

```css
.refresh {
  width: 150px;
}

.btn-refresh {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  background-color: gray;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.timer {
  width: 100px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="refresh">
  <button class="btn-refresh">Обновить страницу</button>
  <div class="timer" data-timer="5 : 00">
    3 : 35
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `document.getElementsByClassName` возвращает коллекцию а не один элемент

Comment: @StrangerintheQ как выбрать 1 элемент?

Comment: `document.getElementsByClassName[0]` или `document.querySelector('.class')`

Comment: или через цикл обработать коллекцию :)

Comment: @StrangerintheQ с этим разобрался. Но основной вопрос "как можно сделать таймер на обновлении страницы?"

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/995388/%d0%95%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%80-%d1%81-%d0%bc%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%b8-%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%87%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%8b/995442#995442

Comment: `meta refresh` не в почете ныне?